# Await kills process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to connect to Azure AD and I am using this code.

```
try
{
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthUri + _tenant);
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUri,clientCredential);
    var authString = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = _requestUri,
    };
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authString);
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(taskWithMessage =>
    {
        response = taskWithMessage.Result;
    });
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

The big problem that I don't understand is that when the execution reaches the first await (`var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUri,clientCredential);`) the process is simply killed. No exception is thrown, nothing.

If I replace that line with

```
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUri,clientCredential); 
var authString = authResult.Result.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

the execution goes on until `await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(taskWithMessage...` where the process is killed again without any exception being thrown or any message of warning or something.

The even weirder thing is that this code runs just fine in another project but here it just wont work.

Edit:

```
static void ImportLicence()
{
   InsertToDb();
}

public async void InsertoDb()
{
   var x = await GetSP();
}

public async Task<Dictionary<ServicePlanViewModel, List<ServicePlanViewModel>>> GetSP()
{
   var sp = await MakeRq();
}

public async Task<string> MakeRequest()
{
   var authString = await GetAuth();
   ..........
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

private async Task<string> GetAuth()
{
   .....
   var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUri, clientCredential);
   return authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
}
```

Comment: Could you ignore `.ContinueWith` and just simply use `async` `await`, don't try to combine both and see if problem repeats.

Comment: @AkashKava the same thing happens. The process is killed.

Comment: @viktorfilim, you are mixing sync and async implementations. Show the method that this code is encapsulated in.

Comment: @Nkosi i have updated the post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the process is simply killed. No exception is thrown, nothing.

I assume that you are running this in a Console application, and that your top-level code would look something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
  MyMethodAsync();
}
```

In which case, the main method would in fact exit, since it is not waiting for your asynchronous code to complete.

One way to work with `async` in Console applications is to block in the `Main` method. Normally, you want to go "async all the way", but a Console app's `Main` method is an exception to this rule:

```
static void Main() => MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
static async Task MainAsync()
{
  // Original code from Main, but adding any necessary `await`s.
  await MyMethodAsync();
}
```

**Update:** [Don't use `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); use `async Task` instead:

```
static async Task ImportLicenceAsync()
{
  await InsertToDbAsync();
}

public async Task InsertoDbAsync()
{
  var x = await GetSPAsync();
}
```

Comment: Same result. I have tried this. This was in my initial code.

Comment: @viktorfilim Then show the code that did that in your question, include all the calls all the way up to `Main()`

Answer (score 1):

Update code so that it is async all the way through. Make sure that you are not mixing async and sync code higher up the call stack. Avoid using `async void`.

```
public async Task<string> SomeMethodAsync() {
    try {
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthUri + _tenant);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUri,clientCredential);
        var authString = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = _requestUri,
        };
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authString);

        using(var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a console application. And the code is async all the way. But the result is the same.